# Why does Chilkat Http experience handshake error at "https" but not at "http"?

Tags: chilkat

The "http" addresses worked fine.
The "https" version gives me a handshake error:

This is the error that I get when I call the following:

```
Dim lSuccess&
lSuccess = nHttp.Download("https://autoconfig.thunderbird.net/v1.1/gmx.de", "d:\weg.xml")
```

lSuccess returns 0 which mean an error occured.

```
ChilkatLog:
  Download:
    DllDate: Aug  1 2014
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.43
    UnlockPrefix: *******
    Username: *******
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: ActiveX
    VerboseLogging: 0
    url: https://autoconfig.thunderbird.net/v1.1/gmx.de
    toLocalPath: d:\weg.xml
    currentWorkingDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98
    a_httpDownload:
      httpDownloadFile:
        localFilePath: d:\weg.xml
        localFileAlreadyExists: 0
        quickHttpRequest:
          httpVerb: GET
          url: https://autoconfig.thunderbird.net/v1.1/gmx.de
          openHttpConnection:
            Opening connection directly to HTTP server.
            httpHostname: autoconfig.thunderbird.net
            httpPort: 443
            ssl: 1
            socket2Connect:
              connect2:
                connectImplicitSsl:
                  clientHandshake:
                    clientHandshake2:
                      processAlert:
                        TlsAlert:
                          level: fatal
                          descrip: handshake failure
                        --TlsAlert
                      --processAlert
                      Failed to read incoming handshake messages. (1)
                    --clientHandshake2
                  --clientHandshake
                  Client handshake failed. (3)
                --connectImplicitSsl
                ConnectFailReason: 0
              --connect2
            --socket2Connect
            ConnectFailReason: 0
            connectElapsedMs: 32
          --openHttpConnection
        --quickHttpRequest
        outputLocalFileSize: 0
        numOutputBytesWritten: 0
        httpDownloadFile failed.
      --httpDownloadFile
      a_httpDownload failed.
    --a_httpDownload
    totalElapsedMs: 47
    Failed.
  --Download
--ChilkatLog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a VERY OLD version of Chilkat.  Update Chilkat to the latest version..   TLS and TLS server requirements evolve over the years.  One cannot expect any implementation to work forever when the external world is always changing..

Comment: The problem is that your control is very popular, and my competitor uses Chilkat, too. And some of my users have both my software on their computer and my competitor's. My competitor didn't update his app for years, but it's more popular than mine. So I keep using the same old Chilkat version that he uses in order not break anything. I have found a way around it. I don't use Chilkat for this special purpose. However I just wanted to explain why I keep using the old version. It's not laziness.